# org.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table X refers to an unmapped class

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-tools

I'm having a problem with the generation of entities from hibernate tools.

I am trying to generate the entities of 4 tables, `pru1` and `pru2` have a relationship many to many in the association table `pru3`. The `pru3` keys pass as foreign keys to the `pru4` table.

```
  pru1 ---> pru3 <---- pru2
              |
              |
              V 
            pru4
```

If I am not mistaken, the entity `pru1` should have a list of `pru2`, `pru2` a list of `pru1` and `pru4` an object of `pru1` and another of `pru2`.

When I run hibernate tools, I get rid of this error:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table PRU4 refers to an unmapped class: com.entities.Pru3
>   An association from the table PRU4 refers to an unmapped class: com.entities.Pru3
>   org.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table PRU4 refers to an unmapped class: com.entities.Pru3
>   An association from the table PRU4 refers to an unmapped class: com.entities.Pru3

In the configuration of hibernate tools I checked all options, including detect many to many tables

Is it possible to do this type of mapping with hibernate tools?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem in a very inelegant way.

Having a relationship that comes from a table that solves an N:N cardinality, it is necessary to create this entity.

I could have unchecked the "Detect many-to-many tables" option, but I have other N:N relationship tables, and these I didn't want to be generated.

The solution I chose was to create an additional field in my PRU3 table, to force hibernate tools to generate the entity.

Later I have erased the field in the BBDD and in the entity.

I'm sure that this type of mapping could be done automatically playing with the reveng.xml or implementing a strategy, but it was going to take me much more time than I have.